# jQuery fadeout not working with declared PHP variable?

Tags: php, jquery, html, fadeout

I have the following code...

PHP/HTML

```
<?php
    if (isset($sent_notification)) {  
        echo "
            <div id='notifyy'> 
                Your message has been sent!
            </div>
            <script>
                document.getElementById('message-header').scrollIntoView();
            </script>
        ";
     }
?>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $( '#notifyy' ).show(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(5000);
    });
</script>
```

This is for a function which sends an email. `$sent_notification` is set to one **if** the email sends, which is why I can't just use a `GET` variable in the form to trigger the JS. However, using the exact same script on the same page with a `GET` variable in place of `$sent_notification`, the *DIV* fades out nicely. Why is the email notification `DIV` failing to fadeout?

Comment: where are you putting the `<script>` relative to the div? If the script comes BEFORE the div, then `$('#notifyy')` will fail because the div doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Yep. You're  right. Didn't  notice. Simple rookie mistake. If you add an answer, I would be happy to accept.

Answer (score 0):

What about putting it into a document ready function? 
and chain the show and fadeout function?

```js
$("#test").show().fadeOut(5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">Fade element</div>
```